# generic list class in c#

Tags: c#, generics, generic-list

I'm currently making my own very basic *generic list class* (to get a better understanding on how the predefined ones work). Only problem I have is that I can't reach the elements inside the array as you normally do in say using "`System.Collections.Generic.List`".

```
GenericList<type> list = new GenericList<type>();
list.Add(whatever);
```

This works fine, but when trying to access "whatever" I want to be able to write **:**

```
list[0];
```

But that obviously doesn't work since I'm clearly missing something in the code, what is it I need to add to my otherwise fully working generic class ?

Comment: What does your `GenericList` class look like?

Comment: Incidentally, one feature which can be useful in a generic list is a method like `public void ActOnElement<TP1>(int index, ActByRef<T,TP1> proc, ref TP1 param1) { proc(ref Array[index], ref TP param1); }` which will allow code to act directly on a list item [assume `public delegate void ActByRef<T1,T2>(ref T1 p1, ref T2 p2);`].  If one has e.g. a `GenericList<Rectangle>`, such a method can allow code to say `myList.ActOnItem(index, (ref Rectangle r, ref int v) => {r.X -= v; r.Width+=v;}, ref widthAdjust)` to update a list item "in-place".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's called an [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6x16t2tx.aspx), written like so:

```
public T this[int i]
{
    get
    {
        return array[i];
    }
    set
    {
        array[i] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect that the OP may mean he is getting `Only assignment, call, increment, decrement and new object expressions can be used as a statement` when accessing the instance of `GenericList`? Obviously if he can't even access the index then your answer is fine :)

Comment: @LukeHennerley I believe the OP was looking for the property declaration to put within their `GenericList` type such that: given an instance of `GenericList list`, they can access an element within it using an indexer eg `list[0]`.

Comment: I suspected as much, was just thinking of how the OP could be mis-interpreted. Anyway, +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

I think all you need to do is implement `IList<T>` , to get all the basic functionality

```
  public interface IList<T>  
  {

    int IndexOf(T item);

    void Insert(int index, T item);

    void RemoveAt(int index);

    T this[int index] { get; set; }
  }
```